# MySQL JOIN two tables query

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables with these structures:

1. customers

   - id_customer
   - customer_name
   - customer_email
   - customer_address
2. orders

   - id_order
   - order_number
   - customer_id
   - order_price
   - payment
   - order_date

I need a query which gives me all "id_customer" from "customers" which are located in table "orders"/"customer_id" WHERE "order_price" > "payment" AND "odrer_date" is minimum 30 days ago

Comment: Have you tried anything before asking?

Comment: Yes: SELECT a.id_customer FROM customers a, orders b WHERE a.id_customer=b.customer_id AND  STR_TO_DATE(b.order_date, '%d.%m.%Y') < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND b.payment<b.order_price

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is, at its heart, a way to manipulate sets. You start with a subquery to determine the set of `customer_id` values match your criteria in the `orders` table.

```
                        SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
                          FROM orders
                         WHERE order_price > payment
                           AND order_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Then you use that subquery to fetch data from your `customers` table.

```
    SELECT *
      FROM customers
     WHERE id_customer IN (
                            SELECT DISTINCT customer_id
                              FROM orders
                             WHERE order_price > payment
                               AND order_date <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
                          )
```

Answer (score -1):

Use This Query

```
 Select * from customers c inner join orders o On c. id_cusomer = o.customer_id 
where o.order_price > o.payment and o.order_date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: Please don't use the old join syntax. Also add explanations.